# Removing Duplicate values from a Cell of DataFramein python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame

```
ID                                                                         Source
 1                     [192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10, 192.168.1.121, 192.168.1.121]
 2          [192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10, 10.1.161.10, 10.1.161.10, 192.168.1.121]
 3                                  [192.168.1.121, 192.168.1.121, 192.168.1.121]
 4                         [10.1.161.10, 192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10, 10.1.161.10]
```

Output I want

```
ID                                Source
 1            192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10
 2            192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10
 3                         192.168.1.121
 4            10.1.161.10, 192.168.1.121
```

Any Help will be Appreciated

Comment: It looks like in your input dataframe the `source` column contains lists, while in the output it is just a string. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Yes, input dataframe the source column contains lists, the output it is just a string.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC Issue is that I want to extract just the unique values from each row of a specific column in DataFrame. Yes I have tried some snippets by referring to the documentation. I hope this answers your queries. Thanks for Enlightening.

Comment: @Pranav101py What was the problem, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pd.unique`:

```
df['source'] = df['source'].apply(
lambda x: ', '.join(pd.unique(x)),
)
```

**Output:**

```
ID                                Source
 1            192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10
 2            192.168.1.121, 10.1.161.10
 3                         192.168.1.121
 4            10.1.161.10, 192.168.1.121
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python set for deduplicating the list

```
df['Source'] = df['Source'].apply(lambda x: ',' .join(set(x)))



    ID  Source
0   1   10.1.161.10,192.168.1.121
1   2   10.1.161.10,192.168.1.121
2   3   192.168.1.121
3   4   10.1.161.10,192.168.1.121
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to delete duplicates in a list which is contained inside a cell. A very basic approach will be to iterate on the column and convert each `list` to `set` and back to `list`.

```
df['Source'] = [list(set(eval(data))) for data in df['Source']]
```

Why `eval` you say? I'll leave that upto you to read on.

Comment: `eval` should only be used when no other way is possible. Here `ast.literal_eval` would be enough

Comment: I agree with you @SergeBallesta. The reason I used `eval` is that in a quite recent project at work I found 'eval' actually was doing more good for my test case.